# Drag and Resize Controls in Shape inside Canvas in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there a way I can attach drag and resize controls on a drawn Rectangle inside Canvas?

I want the user to have the ability drag and resize the Shape with touch/tap gestures around on Canvas' surface.

Anyone has any idea what libraries to use to implement this in Xamarin?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dCvu.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `drag` and `drop` gesture recognizers to the control you want. A `drag` and `drop` gesture enables items, and their associated data packages, to be dragged from one onscreen location to another location using a **continuous gesture**. For the `resizing`, you can refer to [Touch Manipulations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/touch).

The following XAML example shows a `DragGestureRecognizer` attached to an Image:

```
<Image Source="monkeyface.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <DragGestureRecognizer />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Add drag and drop gesture recognizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/drag-and-drop).

Comment: I haven't heard from you for a few days. May I confirm if there is anything else that I can help?